# How can we deploy jupyterhub to kubernetes without using helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, devops, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

For some reasons, I cannot use the helm chart given [here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) inside my premise. Is there any reference how can we do this?

Comment: Can you confirm me your `helm version`?

Comment: @willrof The issue is I can't use helm repo inside my premise.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can deploy JupyterHub without using Helm.**

Follow the tutorial on: [Jupyterhub Github Installation page](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub#installation)

**But,**

**The Helm installation was created to automate a long part of the installation process.**

- I know you can't maintain external Helm repositories in your premise, but you can download manually the package, and install it.
- It will be really easier and faster than creating the whole setup manually.

---

**TL;DR:** The only thing different [From Documentation](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup-jupyterhub.html) will be this command:

```
helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub-0.8.2.tgz \
--namespace jhub \ 
--version=0.8.2 \ 
--values config.yaml
```

Bellow is my full reproduction of the local installation.

```sh
user@minikube:~/jupyterhub$ openssl rand -hex 32
e278e128a9bff352becf6c0cc9b029f1fe1d5f07ce6e45e6c917c2590654e9ee

user@minikube:~/jupyterhub$ cat config.yaml 
proxy:
  secretToken: "e278e128a9bff352becf6c0cc9b029f1fe1d5f07ce6e45e6c917c2590654e9ee"

user@minikube:~/jupyterhub$ wget https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/jupyterhub-0.8.2.tgz
2020-02-10 13:25:31 (60.0 MB/s) - ‘jupyterhub-0.8.2.tgz’ saved [27258/27258]

user@minikube:~/jupyterhub$ helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub-0.8.2.tgz \
--namespace jhub \ 
--version=0.8.2 \ 
--values config.yaml

Release "jhub" does not exist. Installing it now.
NAME: jhub
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Feb 10 13:27:20 2020
NAMESPACE: jhub
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
Thank you for installing JupyterHub!
You can find the public IP of the JupyterHub by doing:
 kubectl --namespace=jhub get svc proxy-public
It might take a few minutes for it to appear!

user@minikube:~/jupyterhub$ k get all -n jhub
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hub-68d9d97765-ffrz6     0/1     Pending   0          19m
pod/proxy-56694f6f87-4cbgj   1/1     Running   0          19m

NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/hub            ClusterIP      10.96.150.230   <none>        8081/TCP                     19m
service/proxy-api      ClusterIP      10.96.115.44    <none>        8001/TCP                     19m
service/proxy-public   LoadBalancer   10.96.113.131   <pending>     80:31831/TCP,443:31970/TCP   19m

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hub     0/1     1            0           19m
deployment.apps/proxy   1/1     1            1           19m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hub-68d9d97765     1         1         0       19m
replicaset.apps/proxy-56694f6f87   1         1         1       19m

NAME                                READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/user-placeholder   0/0     19m
```

If you have any problem in the process, just let me know.